# Merge two ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two identical array lists in java each having a string value and an integer count. Now I have to merge these array lists into a single one, in which if the value is present, i will just increment the count, if the value is not present, i will just add the value and the count as such.

The question is, is there anyway I can do it graciously other than iterating in a for loop and if checking every value?

Comment: could you give some example input/output pairs? your question is a little vague, and that could clear it up a bit

Comment: Use Collection.addAll method.

Comment: A map can be useful in task like this.

Comment: @mfrankli Editing my question right now with an example.

Comment: @RangiLin the problem is i get the arraylist from another system over which I don't have control :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, there's too much custom logic. Iterate, check and add - that's the best approach, and will be more readable.

Technically, you can use a `Multiset` from guava, but there the count is taken care of by the collection itself, rather than you, so it might require some more work.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, is there anyway I can do it graciously other than
>   iterating in a for loop and if checking every value?

Short answer is no.

You would be better of using HashMap as a container, at least the merging operation would perform faster. You need a loop in any case. (since there is no addAll / putAll wich could update your counts).